# Need to create a mail generator, doing templates for differents mails

Tags: c#, json

i need to create an email generator, using templates for differents kind of mails.
I did something really easy, doing replaces on the html, using tags.
It works, but now, i need something more generic.
Let me explain little more:
I have differents json, which i use to replace tags into html  templates, for example:

```
{
    "Minutes": 60,
    "Machines": [
        {
           "Name": "Machine1",
           "Id": "4768"
        },
        {
           "Name": "Machine2",
           "Id":"6502"
        }
    ]
}
```

In this one, i use MINUTES for de subject, and with the array of MACHINES, i make `<href>`

Here is another example:

```
{
    "Threshold": 12,
    "Server": [
        {
           "Name": "Machine1",
           "CpuUsage": 27,
           "RamUsage": 62
        },
        {
           "Name": "Machine2",
           "CpuUsage": 25,
           "RamUsage": 57
        }
    ]
}
```

In this one, i need to make a Table of SERVERS.
An like this, i have lot of more jsons, which should be replaced into html template.

Which is the best way to make it generic, so, the next time i need to create another template, should be easy, just make the json format, and according to that do the  template html, and it should works automatically, without coding.
Thanks!

Comment: We use [hogan.js](http://twitter.github.io/hogan.js/) as client side (JS) templating engine. It should work pretty seamless with JSON data.

Comment: You can do this server-side by using the Razor view engine.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem a while ago and I've solved it using SmartFormat (https://github.com/scottrippey/SmartFormat). Basicly you create some object (or object can be created from deserialized json string) that you will pass it to SmartFormat to format your text. E.g.

```
var fmtObj = new
{
  UserFullName = "...",
  UserUserName = "...",
  WebAppUrl = "...",
  DownloadLink = "...",
  UnsubscribeLink = "...",
};
```

Can be anonymous or full class. And if, for example you have this HTML:

```
var htmlBody = "Hello, <b>{UserFullName}</b>," +
               "<br><br>Your account has been created!" +
               "<br><br>Go to {WebAppUrl} to login!";
```

You can use a call to Smart.Format:

```
var formattedBody = Smart.Format(htmlBody, fmtObj);
```

And in `formattedBody` you have your formatted text. And it also works for properties that are classes themselves (e.g. `User.FullName`)

Comment: It`s like doing replaces. I need to put something of logic into the html, for example, if i have this json: {"Minutes":60,"Machines":[{"Name":"Machine1","Id":"4768"},{"Name":"Machine2","Id":"6502"}]}, the template should have an href for de Machines.

Comment: I doubt that would be possible, because as I understand, you want to generate visually different templates based on JSON that is passed in (e.g. example above would generate HREFs for machines, another JSON would generate table for something, etc.). I think you should generate several template types and use appropriate type based on JSON sent in).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is creating a View(cshtml file) and Send a Model to it. The view is just like a template that gives you freedom to create a nice email:

1. Create a View
2. Create a Model for the View(ViewModel)
3. Add the bellow function to your controller:

   ```
   protected string RenderPartialViewToString(string viewName, object model)
   {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
           viewName = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

       ViewData.Model = model;

       using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
       {
           ViewEngineResult viewResult =     ViewEngines.Engines
           .FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
       ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);

       viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

       return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
       }
   }
   ```
4. Call the above function from your action:

   ```
   var partialView = RenderPartialViewToString("_EmailView",
                       new EmailViewModel()
                       {
                           Email = user.Email,
                           UserName = user.UserName,
                           ...
                       });
   ```
5. The partialView variable now contains the html body of the email and you can send it. Finished!